# Recursive and massive string replace inside Windows folder

Tags: windows, sed, find-and-replace, string-manipulation

I have a text file with `oldstr<tab>newstring` lines to replace inside all source files like this:

```
MyOldText    (tab)   MyNewText
MyOldText2   (tab)   MyNewText2
```

How can I massively replace given text in all files inside a specific folder or subfolders (it's a source code folder with many nested subfolders).

i tried with `sed` for Windows, but I cannot loop on all folders and all occurence of tab separated file

Comment: What IDE are you using? Most of them have a way to do project-wide search and replace. I often just copy an example of the tab from a file and just paste it in the search and replace dialog.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, but I found only massive replace for a single pair of string

Comment: You can do regular expressions too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372748/eclipse-regular-expression-search-and-replace

Comment: The problem is that the list of replacement is a file with couple from->to I don't want to run manually N replacement

Comment: Can you not come up with a regular expression that covers all n cases? That is what I am suggesting. Otherwise yes you will have to run once for each case. Or write a script that does and have it recurse the directory structure.

Comment: It was not regular but human text strings at the end I wrote a php scrit to loop on directory and on string couples to replace, it took a while but It worked. Anyway thanks.

Comment: You should really look into what a regular expression is. They are awesome.